# HTML form center drop down list selection where selected = “selected” using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form that has a dropdown lists.

I would like that the list is centered where the selection is selected. The form has been hard coded to make it simple to follow.

```
    <select id="primary_cat_select" name="primary_cat" size="9" style="width: 400px;">
 <option value="01">001</option>
    <option value="02">002</option>
    <option value="03">003</option>
    <option value="04">004</option>
    <option value="05">005</option>
    <option value="06">006</option>
    <option value="07">007</option>
    <option value="08">008</option>
    <option value="09">009</option>
    <option value="10">010</option>
    <option value="11 selected="selected"">011</option>
    <option value="12">012</option>
    <option value="13">013</option>
    <option value="14">014</option>
    <option value="15">015</option>
    <option value="16">016</option>
    <option value="17">017</option>
    <option value="18">018</option>
    <option value="19">019</option>
    <option value="20">020</option>
    <option value="21">021</option>
    <option value="22">022</option>
    <option value="23">023</option>
    <option value="24">024</option>
    </select>
```

I have a jQuery code as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
 $(function(){

  var form1 = $('#form1'), 
      form2 = $('#form2');  
  //  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).change(function(){
    $(':input[name]', form2).val(function(){
      return $(':input[name='+ this.name +']', form1).val();
    });
  });

});
    </script>
```

I would like to modify the above jQuery code to center the selection where selected="selected" in this case at option 11 i.e. 011

I want to center the selection as in http://jsfiddle.net/BA39h/1/
I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: so whats the difference between the code in that fiddle and what you're trying to do?

Comment: The difference is that the one in jsfiddle does not have selected="selected" in my case I want it to center where it has already been hard coded selected="selected". Thanks

Comment: so you only want to center the one that is `selected=selected`?

Comment: @jmore009 yes, that is what I am after. In my example above it is hard coded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could wrap your script in a function and call it on page load. Just use `setTimeout` to assure that it gets fired after the page is loaded:

```
var start = $("#listF");

setTimeout(function(){
  centerSelect(start);
},1);


$('#listF').on('change', function(){
    centerSelect($(this));
});


function centerSelect(optionChosen){
    strip = optionChosen[0];
     var n = strip.getAttribute('size'),
        i = strip.selectedIndex,
        l = strip.length;
    strip.selectedIndex = Math.min(l-1,i+n/2|0);
    strip.selectedIndex = Math.max(0,i+1-n/2|0);
    strip.selectedIndex = i;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BA39h/12/)

**UPDATE**

For mulltiple `select` fields you can use a `.each()` function to loop through them and run the function:

```
$("select").each(function(){
   var start = this;

   setTimeout(function(){
     centerSelect(start);
   },1);

});
```

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BA39h/15/)

Comment: It seems to work. How can I use your above code for multiple select lists. It works on `var start = $('#primary_cat_select')` but it does not work on `var start = $('#primary_cat_select, #secondary_cat_select, #tertiary_cat_select');`